# how to open a file in two split windows?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, webstorm

I split the editor

and I want to show the file in the both sides of the editor,

most probably this is too easy but I can't find how to do that,

edit:
I find a way, I close all other files, and keep only the target file, and then I split the editor. now phpstorm will show the file in both windows. and then I reopen other files. but I don't think this is smart. Probably there is a better way.

thank you

[image]

Comment: Split that file -- it will create another split (so you will have 3 splits now). Then move tab from newly created split into existing one (2 splits now).

Comment: how to split the file?

Comment: I find a way, I close all other files, and keep only the target file, and then I split the editor. now phpstorm will show the file in both windows. and then I reopen other files. but I don't think this is smart. Probably there is a better way.

Comment: Screenshots please (screencast will be even better). I do not understand what problems you are having and why you need to close all files in order to split the tab.

Comment: To split a tab, just right click on editor tab and choose `Split Vertically` or `Split Horizontally` -- that's it. If you want to move file into separate split (instead of having the same file in both splits) then just use `Move Right` or `Move Down` instead.

Comment: ok, I split tabs. right tab, left tab. I want one file to open in both tabs in the same times.

Comment: When you split, the file will be opened in 2 split at the same time. Is not this is what you want? Once again: screenshots please.

Comment: I added a screenshot, please look at the question above.

Comment: I see that you have "Billing.php" opened in 2 splits. What is the problem -- what needs to be done now? Have "BillingController.php" in 2 split as well?

Comment: Yes, that will answer my question enough.

Comment: well -- **please do what I have said in my very first comment:** 1) split "BillingController.php" -- now you will have 3 splits: A) Billing + BillingController; B) Billing; C) BillingController; 2) Move BillingControoler (using mouse) from newly created split C into B.

Comment: :) I'm sorry, when you say "split the file" I didn't understand what that means. now, I right click the file tab itself and I find the command "split vertically". Now I get your answer.

Comment: BTW, would you please suggest a better rephrase to this question so that it becomes more useful? or do you suggest removing it at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In general:** to split current tab in editor:

- `Right click` on editor tab
- choose `Split Horizontally` or `Split Vertically`
- you can also use `Move Down` or `Move Right` -- but this will move editor tab into new split instead of "copying" it.

Let's assume you have this setup (notice "test.php" is already located in both splits): 
[image]

Now you want to have "css.css" to be in both splits as well. Depends on your IDE version you will have **2 choices**:

**1)** Split this file -- you will have 3 splits now:
[image]

Using mouse move "css.css" from newly created split into existing split:
[image]

**2)** Use **`Open in Opposite Group` action**
[image]

Comment: What if I don't want the window split -- I just want the same file opened in two separate tabs that I can switch between? I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In newest version (my 2021.2) found this option here:
Window -> Editor Tabs -> Split Right/Split Down
[image]